# Decrease the number of elif blocks

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, query-optimization

I 'm trying to do a filter based on the following `queryparams`.

How can I decrease the lines of code:

```
if fridge == 'true' and toilet == 'true' and side_window == 'true':
    queryset = queryset.filter(toilet=True, fridge=True, sun_side_window=True)
elif fridge == 'true' and toilet == 'true':
    queryset = queryset.filter(toilet=True, fridge=True)
elif fridge == 'true' and side_window == 'true':
    queryset = queryset.filter(sun_side_window=side_window.capitalize(), fridge=fridge.capitalize())
elif toilet == 'true' and side_window == 'true':
    queryset = queryset.filter(sun_side_window=side_window.capitalize(), toilet=toilet.capitalize())
elif fridge == 'true':
    queryset = queryset.filter(fridge=fridge.capitalize())
elif toilet == 'true':
    queryset = queryset.filter(toilet=toilet.capitalize())
elif side_window == 'true':
    queryset = queryset.filter(sun_side_window=True)
```

Comment: Definitely. To take it one step further, I think that it **cannot** increase. How are you getting the `fridge`, etc?

Comment: In some instances you have for example `sun_side_window=side_window.capitalize()` and in others `sun_side_window=True`. What type are the fields?

Comment: @Kendas fields are `sun_side_window` from frontend response it's `true` so that's why

Comment: @Ev.Kounis fridge is comes from response

Comment: @Zorig: `side_window.capitalize()` does not equal `True`, it equals `"True"`, a string (notice the quotes).

Answer (score 4):

*I am assuming that by `'true'.capitalize()`, you mean the Boolean value `True`, and not the string `'True'`*

First, convert `'true'` to `True`.
Then, build a dictionary that holds the keyword arguments to be passed to `queryset.filter`.
I am doing these two steps in one single dictionary comprehension:

```
vars = {'fridge': fridge, 'toilet': toilet, 'side_window': side_window}
kwargs = {kw: True for kw in vars if vars[kw] == 'true'}
```

If you are unfamiliar with the comprehensions, this is equivalent to:

```
kwargs = {}
for kw in vars:
    if vars[kw] == 'true':
        kwargs[vars] = True
```

Then unpack this dictionary, and pass it to `queryset.filter`:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(**kwargs)
```

Unpacking the dictionary is equivalent to passing its key/value pairs as keyword arguments to the function.

```
f(a=1, b=2)
# is equivalent to
kw = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
f(**kw)
```

As a side note, I don't know of `queryset`, but it looks like a module.
If so, I would not suggest to reassign the result of `queryset.filter` to `queryset`...

Comment: `queryset` is probably an instance of Django's `QuerySet`. The `filter` method returns a new `QuerySet` instance: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#filter

Comment: @Kendas Yeah I was assuming that was something like this. But anyway, `foo = foo.bar()` looks sort of confusing...

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a function like

```
def q(**kwargs):

    for k in kwargs:
        if kwargs[k] == 'true':
            kwargs[k] = True

    return queryset.filter(**kwargs)
```

You just need to map `sun_side_window` to `side_window` somehow, or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
k = {}
if fridge == "true": 
    k["fridge"] = True
if toilet == "true": 
    k["toilet"] = True
if side_window == "true": 
    k["sun_side_window"] = True
q = queryset.filter(**k)
```

Comment: Don't you think that this will scale poorly? If the number of variables increases, the number of `if` blocks will do so, which will result in more or less the same problem as the original one - although the blocks are granted shorter. By the way, I think it would be nice if you added an explanation of your code and of what it adds to the other solutions.

Comment: Yes, for more variables your solution with a pre-initialized dictionary should be more handy.